# How to assign specific class according to number of elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've this markup as

```
<div id="one" class="content">
    <a href="#">a</a>
    <a href="#">b</a>
    <a href="#">c</a>
</div>
<div id="two" class="content">
    <a href="#">d</a>
    <a href="#">e/a>
</div>
<div id="three" class="content">
    <a href="#">f</a>
</div>
```

Is there a way in which according to the number of `a` elements in each `div.content`, I can assign a different class to the `div.content` element.

For example, in `div#one`, I've 3 `a` elements, so I'll do `$('div#one').addClass('three-img')`; in `div#two`, I've 2 `a` elements, so I'll do `$('div#two').addClass('two-img')` while in `div#three`, I've only 1 `a` element, so I'll do `$('div#three').addClass('one-img')`.

The following jQuery codes work for only `div#one`. What I want is a generic code which will be applied to every `div.content` in the page (there could be unknown number of `div.content` elements having either 1 or 2 or 3 `a` elements inside it.

```
if($('#one a').length == 3){
    $('#one a').parent().addClass('three-img');
} else if($('#one a').length == 2){
    $('#one a').parent().addClass('two-img');
} else if($('#one a').length == 1){
    $('#one a').parent().addClass('one-img');
}
```

Comment: Use .each() to iterate, count the <a>'s and build the class dynamicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
var classes = { 1: 'one-img', 2: 'two-img', 3: 'three-img' };

$('div.content').each( function() {
  var content = $(this);
  content.addClass( classes[content.children().length] );
});
```

Check a [test here](http://jsfiddle.net/DdJGj/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.content').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass(i + 'img');
});
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$(".content").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("img_" + $(this).find("a").length);
});
```

That assumes your classes are named `img_1`, `img_2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help? You can loop through all the div with the class content and get the current divs children

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.content").each(function(e){
            var numberofchildren = $(this).find("a").length;
            if(numberofchildren == 3){
                $(this).addClass("three-img")   
            } 
            else if(numberofchildren == 2){
                $(this).addClass("two-img") 
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("one-img")     
            }
        });
    });
```

Or you can add the class dynamically as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.content").each(function(e){
            var numberofchildren = $(this).find("a").length;
            $(this).addClass("img-" + numberofchildren);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbtxt = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$('.content').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(numbtxt[$('a', this).length-1]+'-img');
});
```

Comment: This would give class two-img to divs with one child, and so on, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just changed it before you commented, figured that out aswell.